# Why does it say nonconformable arrays?

Tags: r

So i have this code. When
Code:

```
return_vector_2 <- rbind(0.08,0.06)
covmatrix_2 <-matrix(c(0.3,0.1,0.1,0.2),nrow=2)
target_return <- 0.1
onevector2 <- rbind(1,1)
onevector2_t <- cbind(1,1)
a2beregnet <- onevector2_t %*% solve(covmatrix_2) %*% onevector2
b2beregnet <- onevector2_t %*% solve(covmatrix_2) %*% Return_vector2
c2beregnet <- t(Return_vector2) %*% solve(covmatrix_2) %*% Return_vector2
d2beregnet <- a2beregnet * c2beregnet - b2beregnet^2
    

optimal_weights_2 <- ((a2beregnet*target_return-b2beregnet)/(d2beregnet)) * solve(covmatrix_2) %*% Return_vector2
+((c2beregnet-target_return*b2beregnet)/(d2beregnet)) %*% solve(covmatrix_2) %*% onevector2
```

Every time i try to run the code, it gets to "optimal_weights_2" and displays the following error message:

> "Error in ((a2beregnet * target_return - b2beregnet)/d2beregnet) * solve(covmatrix_2) %*%  :
> non-conformable arrays"

How is this fixed? Because, technically, nothing should be wrong, since multiplication between a scalar and matrix has never been an issue before.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please correct the typos in your code.  Try running it yourself to discover where they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `(a2beregnet*target_return-b2beregnet)/(d2beregnet)` is read like a 1x1 matrix, not a number.

```
as.numeric((a2beregnet*target_return-b2beregnet)/(d2beregnet))
```

should solve the problem.